@TypeDefs and @TypeDef equivalent in hibernate 6
As a part of springboot migration from 2.3 to 3.0.13 I've the below classes which comes from the springboot 2.3 It seems that annotations @TypeDef and @TypeDefs are removed how to make below code comptible with hibernate 6 and springBoot3
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;

import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseCustomTypeEntity {} 

`
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Test extends BaseCustomTypeEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "source")
    private String source;

    @Column(name = "scope_id")
    private Integer scopeId;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "triggered_at")
    private Date triggeredAt;

    @Column(name = "test")
    private String test;

    @Column(name = "test1")
    private String test1;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "closed_at")
    private Date closedAt;

    @Column(name = "test22")
    private String test22;

    @Column(name = "te")
    private String te;

    @Column(name = "e")
    private String e;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "acknowledged_data", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private AcknowledgedData acknowledgedData;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "df", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, String> df;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "dc", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, String> dc;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "dl", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, String> fl;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "rdl", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<String, String> rdl;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "time")
    private Date time;

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    private void onUpdate() {
        updatedTimestamp = new Date();
    }
}`

getting error as org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreeCreationException to JPA PersistenceException : Could not locate TableGroup - com.dummmy.test.test2.model.entity.Test
